# MySQL - Convert "hh:mm PM" to unix timestamp

Tags: mysql

**Given** - Due to some bad design (legacy), one of the columns in my table(named **delivery_time**) has 'delivery time' stored as string in the format '**hh:mm PM**'. I have another column (named **delivery_date**) with 'date' data type with format **yyyy-mm-dd**.

**What to do** - Using the information in these two columns I need to find date (day and time) in unix timestamp..

I was able to convert **delivery_date** to unix timestamp using the following function -

```
unix_timestamp(cast(delivery_date as date))
```

Can anyone suggest how to take care of **delivery_time** column?

Comment: Try using [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  It's the opposite of [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and uses the same formatting codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not verified but i guess this will work for you

```
SELECT   
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(delivery_date, ' ', 
STR_TO_DATE(delivery_time,'%h:%i %p)) AS  
my_unix_timestamp
```